# Cannot log in with MyOpenId (delegated to own domain)

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, login, myopenid

I've used http://timothy.green.name to log into SO before, but now it's not working for me (past two days).

The following message appears on the log-in page:

> **Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: The signature verification
>   failed.**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Incidentally, I don't use OpenID logins on any other sites, so I can't really test it. Any suggestions for sites to join with OpenID? I believe Facebook has it, but the "log in with OpenID" page is well hidden.

Comment: Tried at Pharyngula and got the error message "An error occurred: The sign-in attempt was not successful; please try again." That suggests it's a problem with MyOpenId, not with Stack Overflow. But I am definitely logged into MyOpenId.

Comment: It should be sorted now; if not, let me know. I'm marking as completed - just add a comment under my reply if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ouch on the "CallVerify". Are you now up and running, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say what is wrong with your current openid, however, let's just get it fixed, eh? I suggest you pick a second OpenID provider - google might make sense, since you can use either gmail or your google profile. Create a second account on SO, and let me know which. In parallel, I'll e-mail the e-mail address **on your original account**; reply to confirm that it is you, and I'll merge the two accounts (you can have 2 OpenID records per account).

Then when (if?) your OpenID works again you can change back easily.

For info, the reason I ask you to create a second SO account is that gmail OpenID is not preditable.

Comment: Got that e-mail. Thanks. Still can't log into SO.

Comment: MyOpenId is completely messing me up now. For some reason I enabled CallVerify, so it phones me when I log in to confirm it's me. CallVerify has now completely stopped working, so it looks like I'm locked out of my OpenId account for good. Grrr! I'll create a second Google account on SO now.

Comment: After about a week of messing about, I finally noticed the "recover account" option on MyOpenId. I have now disabled CallVerify and can get in (finally!). But it's still not working on SO. :(

Comment: My OpenId account is now up and working fine for all sites other than SO and Meta SO. It works on Blogger and on Pharyngula. http://stackoverflow.com/users/209139/trig and http://stackoverflow.com/users/237093/trig and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139958/trig are all the same person. Can these accounts be merged?

Comment: And any idea why MyOpenId isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

Try logging into http://test-id.org/OP/Sreg.aspx with your MyOpenID and see if it works for you.  If you ever see a failure, quickly visit http://test-id.org/TracePage.aspx, copy down the whole page and send it to dotnetopenid@googlegroups.com for analysis.  But I agree... it's probably a fault on the myopenid.com side.

Comment: Logged in there no problem.

Comment: And it found my nickname, country, language and all.